# GET requests threw irb/rails console extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, get, httpclient

I am making a GET request to an external site in my rails app, and it is extremely slow(60+ seconds per request) no matter which website I try and load.
I have tried using the following services, and all have the same problem. 
Net/HTTP. 
HTTParty
RestClient

I have even tried changing my DNS to use a public one, flushed the DNS cache. Yet still no improvement. Even restarted my computer, to see if that would have any improvement. 
Doing cURL requests or browsing through a web browser, works quite well.

Testing this on my spare computer, everything seems to work fine.
I am not sure what is causing the slowness on this computer, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once where ruby* was first trying to use ipv6, timing out, and then falling back to ipv4.  Curl has a flag to force ipv6 -- try that and see if you experience the same slowness.  If so, that might be a good candidate to investigate further.

* It might not have been ruby, but for purposes of this answer, it doesn't really matter.